# How to change image within a customised UIImageView class

Tags: xcode, image, uiimageview, touch

I'm new to Xcode. This is probably a very simple question to you, but I wonder if anyone can help me.

What I want to do is to load an image in a customised UIImageView, when clicking the image, the imageview will change to another image. When I run the simulator, there are no error messages, but the second image does not load after clicking.

I've declared **a UIImageView subclass dragView**. In the **dragView.m**, I have such codes:

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
[self changePicture];
}

-(void) changePicture {
  NSString *path = [[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Red Flower.png"];
  self.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];    
}
```

By the way, I have enabled the interaction. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to tell the OS to update the view by calling `[self setNeedsDisplay:YES]`.